# Why does the sodium become transparent after burning?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

I know that if we throw a piece of sodium into water then it will melt first then it will explode.

But under different conditions, the above situation will not happen. If we keep a piece of sodium on a wet cloth then it will not explode. Rather, it will burn and turn into a transparent small ball and then the ball will bust. ([Video of example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJGVZNth68k).)

What is the reason behind such situation? What reaction actually occurs when the sodium is kept on wet cloth?

Comment: Videos/links? Have you tried this (of course with proper safety equipment)?

Comment: Exactly the same one...

Comment: Yeah same one but no answers there , I think you did not watch full video , he said he even don't know what happens in that situation.

Comment: I'd surmise that it is an "optical delusion" due to sodium melting into a near sphere with a very high reflectivity since the surface is pure clean metal with no oxide coating.

Comment: 17 days passed  I got no answer ?